# AlarmManager not stopping previous PendingIntent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a function where I set a **15 minute** repeating alarm to start my service, which calls a webservice, processes the result and closes. Simplified:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context cx) {
    try{
        //My service is running, no need to reset the alarm
        if (isServiceRunning())
            return;

        Intent intent = new Intent(cx, ResultService.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(cx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        //My pending intent exists, no need to reset the alarm
        if (sender!=null)
            return;

        sender = PendingIntent.getService(cx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) cx.getSystemService(cx.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Cancel any previous alarms????
        am.cancel(sender);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstRun, interval, sender);
    }catch (Exception e){           
    }
}
```

This is called by a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the following events

```
ACTION_SCREEN_ON
ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
```

via

```
setAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());
```

It seems to work however I start seeing multiple calls to my webservice **per second** on random devices.

I have tried getting it to happen whilst debugging with no success.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

I ran

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt
```

to check the alarm lock and I see the number of wakeups/alarms increases every time the alarm manager executes my PendingIntent:

```
 com.x

279ms running, 22 wakeups

22 alarms: flg=0x4 cmp=com.x/.service.ResultService
```

Does it mean anything?

**UPDATE 2**

I tracked one of the offending devices.

It calls the web service as it should for most of the day, then suddenly at 19:53 last evening I get 330 extra calls from the device in 6 seconds.

Afterwards it runs fine until 06:50 this morning when I get 282 extra calls and on 06:55 I get another 130 extra calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
int RQS=1;
//RQS- request id for starting the alram ,get the same request and cancel
// starting the alarm
intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Receiver.class);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
//cancelling the request
alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: I already use 0 as my request id in both the cancel() and setRepeating()?
Also your code uses getBroadcast() where I am using getService, is just an example or of significance?

Comment: Am implementing broad cast receiver, from that am calling service class.Am shown a example. use getservice() instead of getBroadcast()

Comment: Well I'm using the same request id for starting and cancelling the alarm, so it's not that

Comment: I have updated the code check it. I have started and stopped with same request id.

Comment: And if you check my code, so do I.
And it does not help remedy the problem